# CollectionView Programatic Scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit

What i am trying to do is scrolling my `CollectionView` to the very bottom as soon as my content has been loaded.

Here is my code;

```
func bindSocket(){
    APISocket.shared.socket.on("send conversation") { (data, ack) in
        let dataFromString = String(describing: data[0]).data(using: .utf8)
        do {
            let modeledMessage = try JSONDecoder().decode([Message].self, from: dataFromString!)
            self.messages = modeledMessage
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
            }
        } catch  {
            //show status bar notification when socket error occurs
        } 
    }
}
```

but it is totally not working.

By the way i'm using `InputAccessoryView` for a sticky data input bar like in iMessage and using `collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive`

thanks,

Comment: It seems the missing point is this statements are trying to scroll collectionview without loading all items...

Answer (score 0):

What I am think about that you maybe call the func before your collectionView getting visible cells or call reload collection view and then scroll items immediately, at this point scroll to indexPath will not make sense, since the collection view's content size is not yet updated.

**scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)**

> Scrolls the collection view contents until the specified item is visible.

try this:

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
let itemAttributes = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
self.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(itemAttributes!.frame, animated: true)
```

Comment: this is not working already.Occasionally when it scrolls, it does not scroll to the last item. When it does not, the collection view comes empty.

Comment: Sorry if you could attach your view controller code I may can help you